# How can one list method_options with thor -T?

Tags: ruby, command-line, thor

When using thor I am used to writing code like this,

```
desc "import", "Import diamonds from the south."                   
method_option :num_diamonds, :type => :numeric, :default => nil               
def import
  diamond_importer = DiamondImporter.new
  diamond_importer.update_maps                                     
  diamond_importer.process_diamonds(options)                               
end
```

When I run the diamond_importer command-line tool with no arguments, or with a -T I get a list of descriptions of tasks like "import", but not description of options like "num_diamonds" or their usage.

How can I add such usage details so that they will be displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default class_option are included in the help, while method_options are only shown when help is called for that task...

```
% diamond_importer help #shows class options as help, and 1 line per task
% diamond_importer help import #shows the class options and method options for the "import" task.
```

to change this you need to override the #help and/or #task_help methods of thor.rb